# mysql pass reference of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join

this query (let f) give me id's  let [4,14,21] of friends of a user_id 1

```
select  u1.id  from friends as f1 
inner join users u1 on u1.id =  CASE f1.to_user WHEN 1 THEN f1.from_user ELSE f1.to_user END 
where f1.to_user=1 or f1.from_user=1
```

and below query calculating common friends among two user (let user & his friends)

```
select  users.id,users.name, 
(SELECT count(distinct f1.id ) FROM friends as f1 WHERE (f1.to_user = (4,14,21) and f1.from_user = users.id) or (f1.to_user = users.id and f1.from_user in (4,14,21)) ) ) as m from friends 
inner join users on users.id =  CASE friends.to_user WHEN 1 THEN friends.from_user ELSE friends.to_user END 
where friends.to_user=1 or friends.from_user=1
```

i'd like to merge two queries into one as below

```
select  users.id,users.name, 
(SELECT count(distinct f1.id ) FROM friends as f1 WHERE (f1.to_user in (f)and f1.from_user = users.id) or (f1.to_user = users.id and f1.from_user in (f) ) ) as m,
(select  u1.id  from friends as f1 inner join users u1 on u1.id = (CASE f1.to_user WHEN 1 THEN f1.from_user ELSE f1.to_user END) where f1.to_user=1 or f1.from_user=1)  as f
from friends inner join users on users.id =  CASE friends.to_user WHEN 1 THEN friends.from_user ELSE friends.to_user END 
where friends.to_user=1 or friends.from_user=1
```

but error ***Subquery returns more than 1 row***,
anyone tell good way to slove this problem

Comment: Can you also post the schema and sample data of your use case?

Comment: schemas 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884132

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your count(distinct f1.id )  return 1 row but `as status`  query return more than a row so you have an error
if you need  only a row form the `as status` query you can use limit 1 in subquery

but if you need  all  the rows  you should join the subquery based  on u1.id

eg:

```
  Select  
         users.id
        , users.name
        , (SELECT count(distinct f1.id ) 
              FROM friends as f1 
              WHERE (f1.to_user in (status)and f1.from_user = users.id) or (f1.to_user = users.id and f1.from_user in (status) ) ) as m
        , t_status.status
  from friends 
  inner join users on users.id =  CASE friends.to_user WHEN 1 THEN friends.from_user ELSE friends.to_user END 
  inner join ( select  u1.id  as status
              from friends as f1 
              inner join users u1 on u1.id = (CASE f1.to_user WHEN 1 THEN f1.from_user ELSE f1.to_user END) 
              where f1.to_user=1 or f1.from_user=1) t_status on t_status.status = users.id
  where friends.to_user=1 or friends.from_user=1
```

if you need  only a rows from the subselect as status  you can arbitrarly get one using limit

```
Select  
       users.id
      , users.name
      , (SELECT count(distinct f1.id ) 
            FROM friends as f1 
            WHERE (f1.to_user in (status)and f1.from_user = users.id) or (f1.to_user = users.id and f1.from_user in (status) ) ) as m
      , (select  u1.id  
            from friends as f1 
            inner join users u1 on u1.id = (CASE f1.to_user WHEN 1 THEN f1.from_user ELSE f1.to_user END) 
            where f1.to_user=1 or f1.from_user=1  
            order by u1.id limit 1)  as status
from friends 
inner join users on users.id =  CASE friends.to_user WHEN 1 THEN friends.from_user ELSE friends.to_user END
```

Comment: first status is not a table, i use this name because i think need to use a column name it's actually result friends. let me update in question

Comment: looking to your code status is an alias for a subselect  .. and i use the subselect as a select join  ...  .. then try format better you code  ..

Comment: oh great you are a step ahead. let me match result set

Comment: sorry @scaisEdge results not match. if have time see schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884132

Comment: I don't know if the result match or not but your question is about an error ..   you have the error or not ?

Comment: in the sqlfiddle the query work  and retunr 3 rows  .. so as 3 are the values  in your subselect that return   [4,14,21]  .. if you have a subselect with 3 rows  you should return a query for 3  rows .. otherwise  if you don't need  3 rows the you must decide if you want only one row and which .. let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153511/discussion-between-shivshankar-and-scaisedge).